# Youtube Api As3 getCurrentTime

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, youtube-api

I am using the Youtube Api for AS3 and i used the function player.getCurrentTime so that I can get the current time of the video. I have been running into this error https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=6215 and I really need to get this fixed is there any solutions to this problem or a way around it. I am just trying to save the current video progress to a variable and access that variable later here is my code used for this function

```
mis_player = new my_players(vidSource, mis_players.my_play.getCurrentTime());
```

and here is the code used for using the var both work fine at first then display the second value as the end of the video

```
my_play.seekTo(currTime1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, by sending the variable through the function I was able to pass the variable through to the function.